# Why/when would ng-content b a good practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, web

Maybe a strange question regarding ng-content / Content projection. I get the idea that you can dynamically put in 'content' which can in turn be projected by using ng-content. One thing I could also do to achieve this is to make an Input property to pass in the information I want to show in the component.

I've come across this project; https://trimox.github.io/angular-mdc-web/#/home
which is the new material components for Angular. One thing I found out while browsing through the code is that he makes extreme use of ng-content to project some 'sub-components'. I cant help but wonder... why?? Because I can also try and solve this using one card component and a JSON/object like configuration which I pass on.

```
<mdc-card class="demo-card">
<mdc-card-primary-action mdc-ripple>
    <mdc-card-media class="demo-card__media--16-9" [wide]="true"></mdc-card-media>
    <div class="demo-card__primary">
        <h2 class="demo-card__title" mdcHeadline6>Our Changing Planet</h2>
        <h3 class="demo-card__subtitle" mdcSubtitle2>by Kurt Wagner</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="demo-card__secondary" mdcBody2>
        Visit ten places on our planet that are undergoing the biggest changes today.
    </div>
</mdc-card-primary-action>
<mdc-card-actions>
    <mdc-card-action-buttons>
        <button mdc-button mdcCardAction="button">Read</button>
        <button mdc-button mdcCardAction="button">Bookmark</button>
    </mdc-card-action-buttons>
    <mdc-card-action-icons>
        <button mdcIconButton mdcCardAction="icon" iconOn="favorite" iconOff="favorite_border"></button>
        <mdc-icon mdcCardAction="icon" mdcRipple>share</mdc-icon>
        <mdc-icon mdcCardAction="icon" mdcRipple>more_vert</mdc-icon>
    </mdc-card-action-icons>
</mdc-card-actions>
```

Above you can see for example a 'card' component with several items in it. I've also found the source for these components; https://github.com/trimox/angular-mdc-web/blob/master/packages/card/card.ts.

My original question remains; when is it a good practice to use ng-content and when it's not. and why is it a good practice? I;ve also see DevExpress use it in their devextreme library; https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RecordGrouping/Angular/Light/

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let me simplify your question. Let's say you want to create a `card` component. You could write your own child components (along with the code to perform the necessary content projection), like this:

```
<card>
   <card-title>My Title</card-title>
   <card-content>
      <p>Content here...</p>
      <card-action>Some button here</card-action>
   </card-content>
   <card-footer>My footer</card-footer>
</card>
```

...or you could just create one `<card>` component and have it take in a configuration object like this:

```
config = {
   title: "My title",
   content: {
      innerHTML: "<p>Content here...</p>",
      actions: [ {type: "button", text: "Some button here", onClick: "myFunction()"} ]
   },
   footer: "My footer"
}
```

So why would you want to go with the first option?

---

**1. Semantic HTML**

One reason is that, in general, it's good practice to separate structure (HTML), presentation (CSS), and behavior (JS / TS). Since a `card` component will probably contain other structural elements like its title, content, actions, footer, etc. it's best to express this structure in the HTML rather than do it through JavaScript/TypeScript. You should let your HTML markup convey the underlying meaning of your content. Doing so makes your code more semantic, clean, maintainable, and human readable. Perhaps if you're just developing an application yourself (rather than working in a team), then there's less of a need to make it semantic/readable to others because you understand your own code. But you should still make it readable for your future self because if you want to review your code a year later, you'll probably want your code to be semantic and easily readable.

**2. Making use of Angular's template synatx**

Another reason for going with the first option (using content projection + child components) is that you can make use of Angular's powerful features, such as data binding and `*ngFor`, in your HTML. For example, if you want to show a list of cards, with each card showing a social media post (like in Facebook), you could easily write:

```
<card *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <card-title>{{post.title}}</card-title>
   <card-content>
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
      <card-action>
         <card-button (click)="likePost(post)">Like</card-button>
         <card-button (click)="sharePost(post)">Share</card-button>
      </card-action>
   </card-content>
   <card-footer>{{post.footer}}</card-footer>
</card>
```

Whereas it would probably be more difficult to implement the same thing with a JS/TS configuration object.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine If you are Passing Data from Parent to Child. Normally we will use Input property binding and we will get the data in child ts and we will bind the data. Instead of doing that ng-content we can place the content inside component tag from parent and bind your parent data and use ng-content inside child so that we can avoid input property binding

**Parent Component**

```
 <parent>
        <child>
             <div class="head">{{heading}}</div>    
         </child>
   </parent>
```

**child component**

```
 <ng-content select=".head"></ng-content>
```

Here we are binding the parent data directly instead of using input property binding to process data